# Can transactions be canceled?

Tags: stardew-valley

In Stardew Valley, after clicking an item to purchase on the transaction screen, can the transaction be canceled, or must the item be placed in your inventory and purchased?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quit out of the game and start the day over. That is about the only thing you can do.